# How to draw yline within specific range of x-axis values?

Tags: graph, stata

Can you please help me to identify the way I can plot yline (that corresponds to the value of 21) within the range of 1991 to 1995 and then yline with value 10 within the range between 1996 and 2000? Below I attach the code that I have so far:

```
serrbar mean error year , scale(2) addplot(line mean year) xscale(r(1995 2000)) title("xxx")  yaxis(1 
2) xtitle("Year",height(6)) ytitle("xx") legend(order( 1 "xx" 2 "xx"))  xline(1995, lcol(red)) 
yline(21,  lpatter(dash)) yline(10,  lpatter(dash)) xlabel(1991(1)2000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, but you can get the same effect.

You don't provide a reproducible example, so here is one.

```
webuse assembly, clear
serrbar mean std date
serrbar mean std date , addplot(function first=180, ra(108 110) || function second=200, ra(113 116)) legend(order(1 2))
```